# Unknown modules in Qt: qml quick, while build

Tags: linux, qt, ubuntu-16.04

Trying to build first qt application based on quick controls in my Ubuntu 16. After wizard was finished I tried to build application. Got error:

```
Unknown module()s in QT:qml quick
```

[image]

How to fix that?

Answer (score 5):

did you try installing `qtdeclarative5-dev`?
Have a look at [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/508503/whats-the-development-package-for-qt5-in-14-04).

Comment: This should be a comment as written.